# Convert long lat tuple into linestring

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I have a dataframe of long/lat tuples and am trying to convert it into a Linestring that I can use in a Geopandas dataframe. The current format is [(-105.279, 40.060), (-105.279, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.058), (-105.282, 40.03)] etc. Is there a library or technique to do this?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202190/turning-geodataframe-of-x-y-coordinates-into-linestrings-using-groupby I hope this helps.

Comment: I did see this, but it's using two columns and converting it to linestring. I could try this, but I was wondering first if there was something out there to do it without going this step.

Comment: You can pass this format directly to `shapely.geometry.LineString` with apply.